# How do I save structured data to file?

Tags: rust

My program contains a huge precomputation with constant output. I would like to avoid running this precomputation in the next times I run the program. Thus, I'd like to save its output to file in the first run of the program, and just load it the next time I run the program.

The output contains non-common data types, object and structs I defined myself.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: What does "non-standard data" mean?

Comment: I would just export it to JSON, which is quite trivial using serde.

Comment: @PeterHall i.e. not String, vec, usize etc.

Comment: @mcarton De/serialization are not implemented for the data types I'm using. Would Serde still work?

Comment: You can derive or write a custom serializer and deserializer. https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html I highly recommended giving those docs and the given examples a look. It cleared up a lot of things for me about `serde`.

Comment: @Jason That's very useful, Thanks!

Comment: After reading the relevant docs and trying to implement, I see this is far from trivial when applying on complex code. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A de-facto standard way for (de-)serializing rust objects is [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde). Given a rust struct (or enum) it produces an intermediate representation, which then can be converted to a desired format (e.g. json). Given a struct:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

// here the "magic" conversion is generated
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct T {
    i: i32,
    f: f64,
}
```

you can get a json representation with simple as oneliner:

```rust
let t = T { i: 1, f: 321.456 };
println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&t).unwrap());
// prints `{"i":1,"f":321.456}`
```

as well as converting back:

```rust
let t: T = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"i":1,"f":321.456}"#).unwrap();
println!("i: {}, f: {}", t.i, t.f);
// prints i: 1, f: 321.456
```

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4cfb0ce22e910da4e432cb5a2e6f0aab) is a playground link. This is an example for [serde_json](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) usage, but you may find other more suitable libraries like [serde_sbor](https://crates.io/crates/serde_cbor), [serde_yaml](https://crates.io/crates/serde_yaml), [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode), [serde_xml](https://crates.io/crates/serde_xml) and many many others.

Answer (score 6):

You would want to use something like [serde](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/) to serialize the data, save it to disk, and then restore it from there on the next run. In particular, [bincode](https://github.com/servo/bincode), is useful to serialize the data in the binary format which saves much more space than JSON or other human readable format. But, you have to be careful not to use old serialized data if you have changed the layout of the structures in your program.

For more in depth, I would go to Serde's documentation, but the basic idea is to mark all your structures that need saving with `#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]`, and use bincode to do the serialization/deserialization. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6bd6ea542877293e8a85cd25419a77c) for an example I wrote using `serde_json` (as bincode is not available in rust playground), but `bincode` is no different, other than using `serialize` and `deserialize` as opposed to `to_vec` and `from_slice`.